# Rake abort error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rake

OK, so I'm doing the following Ruby tutorial: https://github.com/alexch/learn_ruby

and I have saved all the files under `c:/learn_ruby`

When I run `rake` in the directory: "00_hello" I get the following error:

```
c:\learn_ruby\00_hello>rake
(in c:/learn_ruby)
rake aborted!
Could not find 'rspec' (~> 2) - did find: [rspec-3.0.0]
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=C:/Users/******/.gem/ruby/1.9.1;C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1
.9.1', execute `gem env` for more information
```

my current gem list is:

```
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.5)
minitest (2.5.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.5)
rspec (3.0.0)
rspec-core (3.0.2)
rspec-expectations (3.0.2)
rspec-mocks (3.0.2)
rspec-support (3.0.2)
rubygems-update (2.3.0)
```

I am new at Ruby, so can someone please help a noob out? I tried installing rspec 2.0.0, but got a different error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
Could not find 'rspec' (~> 2)
```

means that it is looking for rspec in the 2.x range. Usually this means you have a `Gemfile` which specifies `gem 'rspec', '~> 2'`. The `~>` ties it to the same version "family"; see the [bundler](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html) docs for more information.

Usually the solution is to type

```
bundle install
```

which will make sure your prerequisites are met.